# Imposing constraints on weights of input layer in NN

Tags: optimization, keras, neural-network

I want to train a NN but I want the weights of the input layer to obey many constraints, more specifically:

- individual weights should be less than a given value (say 0.05)
- sum of the weights should be 0.96
- the weights obey a set of equations (all solvable)

How do I achieve this in Keras? I know about e.g. max_norm to act on the weight vector w but I don't know how to impose a constraint on the single weight w_i.

The network architecture is not really important here, except that the input layer has 76 features and the output layer has a single output, which should be 10. Also, I have an initial vector of weights for the 76 features.

My point is the following: I have a result of an optimization with constraints coming from a different domain, and I want to feed the result of such optimization to a NN so that I can readjust the weights of the initial 76 features if I get closer to the target value of 10. However, the constraints must still be fullfilled.

Comment: What do you mean by input layer weights? Input layer does not have weights. For rest of layers see [constrains](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/constraints) or [regularizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers). I am not sure if there is a way to make weights obey an equation but you can put some equation in loss function though.

Comment: You mean you wanna your initialized weights to follow those constraints?

Comment: I am talking about weights from input to fisrt hidden layer and i mean that they have to obey a set of rules after each round of forward and backrprop